# set a minimum limit of addition results

Tags: delphi

I have addition process of variable `num: Cardinal` added by `RandomRange(-20, 21)` in my program. But whenever `num` has a value like 19 and `RandomRange` returns a value of -20, the result becomes <0. How do I set the minimum limit of results to 0?

Comment: `num := num + RandomRange(-min(20, num), 21);`

Comment: @Lumpia: You haven't completely defined the precise desired behaviour of your operation. Most likely you want either MBo's `num := num + RandomRange(-min(20, num), 21)` *or* `num := Max(0, num + RandomRange(-20, 21))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can refine and limit the randomrage function input values so that they always have a value of <0.

I think that might help.

Comment: I think the OP likely knows that - he's asking how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
num := num + System.Math.Max(0, RandomRange(-min(20, num), 21));
```

Comment: Not particularly likely. This will make `num` an increasing sequence. The range of `System.Math.Max(0, RandomRange(-min(20, num), 21))` is the same as that of `RandomRange(0, 21)` but the distribution is different.